# I am Unable to run jenkins job to run maven project?

Tags: maven, automation, continuous-integration

It's getting bellow errors in console.out file.How to fix this issue?But i am able to run this program using idea without any error .

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test.package ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Compiling 21 source files to C:\Users\Sadisha\IdeaProjects\OSSPortal\target\test-classes
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] C:\Users\src\test\java\BaseTestScripts\OSSHomePageObject.java:[3,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    [ERROR] C:\Users\Sadisha\IdeaProjects\OSSPortal\src\test\java\BaseTestScripts\OSSHomePageObject.java:[4,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    [ERROR] C:\Users\Sadisha\IdeaProjects\OSSPortal\src\test\java\BaseTestScripts\OSSHomePageObject.java:[5,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    [ERROR] C:\Users\Sadisha\IdeaProjects\OSSPortal\src\test\java\BaseTestScripts\OSSHomePageObject.java:[6,33] error: package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
    [ERROR] C:\Users\Sadisha\IdeaProjects\OSSPortal\src\test\java\BaseTestScripts\OSSHomePageObject.java:[7,39] error: package org.openqa.selenium.interactions does not exist
    [ERROR] C:\Users\Sadisha\IdeaProjects\OSSPortal\src\test\java\BaseTestScripts\OSSHomePageObject.java:[8,37] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
```

My Specs :
windows 10

Comment: Are you having the Selenium Dependency in your pom file. Can you add the pom.xml file to your description.

Comment: Yes i did the changed in the pom file to update the dependencies .Now it's working fine .